# Can't build AudioKit frameworks under High Sierra (10.13.x)

Tags: ruby, xcode, terminal, macos-high-sierra, audiokit

I am getting the output below and a stuck terminal session when building AudioKit 4.x frameworks on macOS 10.13.

```
Building frameworks for platforms: iOS macOS tvOS
./build_frameworks.sh: /usr/local/bin/xcpretty: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

High Sierra comes with Ruby 2.3 and AudioKit seems to specifically require Ruby 2.0. I can't find exactly where to un-configure this. Other options could involve multiple Ruby installations. Seems more likely though that I am missing something essential. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can avoid this problem by editing the lines in build_frameworks.sh:

```
if which xcpretty > /dev/null 2>&1;
then
    XCPRETTY=xcpretty
else
    XCPRETTY=cat
fi
```

and just use

```
XCPRETTY=cat
```

You'll lose the beautified output, but it should work.

Comment: Yes - you are correct. Frameworks are compiling as I write this ;}

Comment: I had this same problem today in 2020. What's the deeper fix - is there something I don't have installed ?